# Log4net doesn't show exact error message

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm using **log4net** as a global exception handler in my .NET Core 2.0 app.

I need to show **exact error message** and **stacktrace**. But at the moment it just say *"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request"*

This is my log4net configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logger.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <IgnoresException value="False" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date %logger [%thread] [%ndc] (%file:%line) %level- %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

***How I can show exact error message and stacktrace?***

Comment: Are you actually handling the exceptions and logging trem?

Comment: I don't handle exceptions manually.. I have logs file. My logger writes it this way - http://prntscr.com/gzqt1z

Comment: that's the problem, i think you don't handle them at all, that is where the unhandled exception comes from. If you handle them and invoke the logger with the exception object, you will get the details you expect